# good resource for socket errors?

Tags: c++, c, sockets

Where can I find a list of all types of bsd style socket errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the documentation? For instance, for connect(), see:

```
% man connect
...
  ECONNREFUSED
          No-one listening on the remote address.
  EISCONN
          The socket is already connected.

  ENETUNREACH
          Network is unreachable.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also find a list of error codes (and a general description of their meaning) on the Open Group's pages for each function (like [connect](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/connect.html), for example).

Answer (score 1):

Of you want to know all possible errno's or some comments on them you could take a look at the header files, on a Linux system there are located in

- /usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h

```
#ifndef _ASM_GENERIC_ERRNO_BASE_H
#define _ASM_GENERIC_ERRNO_BASE_H

#define EPERM        1  /* Operation not permitted */
#define ENOENT       2  /* No such file or directory */
#define ESRCH        3  /* No such process */
#define EINTR        4  /* Interrupted system call */
#define EIO      5  /* I/O error */
#define ENXIO        6  /* No such device or address */
#define E2BIG        7  /* Argument list too long */
#define ENOEXEC      8  /* Exec format error */
#define EBADF        9  /* Bad file number */
#define ECHILD      10  /* No child processes */
#define EAGAIN      11  /* Try again */
...
```

- /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h

```
#ifndef _ASM_GENERIC_ERRNO_H
#define _ASM_GENERIC_ERRNO_H

#include 

#define EDEADLK     35  /* Resource deadlock would occur */
#define ENAMETOOLONG    36  /* File name too long */
#define ENOLCK      37  /* No record locks available */
#define ENOSYS      38  /* Function not implemented */
#define ENOTEMPTY   39  /* Directory not empty */
#define ELOOP       40  /* Too many symbolic links encountered */
#define EWOULDBLOCK EAGAIN  /* Operation would block */
...
```

If you want to know what errno a call, e.g. socket() or connect() can return, when install the development manpages and try man socket or man connect

Answer (score 1):

Many functions will set `errno` on failure, and instead of going through `errno.h` yourself and converting the error number to strings, you are much better off calling [`perror`](http://www.rt.com/man/perror.3.html).

`perror` will print the current `errno`'s corresponding message to `stderr` with an optional prefix.

Example usage:

```
if (connect())
{
    perror("connect() failed in function foo");
    ...
}
```

`perror` has friends called `strerror` and `strerror_r` who might prove useful if you want to capture the string for use in places other than `stderr`.